# What's the best practice in creating font-variables with multiple properties in scss?

Tags: css, sass, liferay

I'm creating a `variables`-file with `scss` for my `Liferay 7` -project and as I'm going to have multiple different text styles, I was wondering what would be the best way to write them? Values below are just examples.

| Text type | Font | Size | Weight | Other properties |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Title 1 | Arial | 1.5rem | 700 |  |
| Title 2 | Calibri | 1.25rem | 500 | #FF0000 |
| Body | Courier | 1rem | 400 |  |
| Link | Arial | 1rem | 400 | underline |

Should I format it as clear and long as possible or should I rather try to fit them inside a single line, or something in between? Shorter seems better in my opinion, but is it too cramped to be understood clearly, if it was in need of modification?

Example 1:

```css
$title1FontFamily: "Arial";
$title2FontFamily: "Calibri";
$bodyFontFamily: "Courier";
$linkFontFamily: "Arial";

$title1FontSize: 1.5rem
$title2FontSize: 1.25rem
$bodyFontSize: 1rem // not really necessary, if base
$linkFontSize: 1rem // not really necessary, if base

// ...

.title1 {
  font-family: $title1FontFamily;
  font-size: $title1FontSize;
  // ...
}

// or

.title2 {
  font: $title2FontFamily $title2FontSize;
}
```

Example 2:

```css
$title1Font: Arial 1.5rem 700;
$title2Font: Calibri 1.25rem 500 #FF0000;
$bodyFont: Courier 1rem 400;
$linkFont: Arial 1rem 400 underline;

.title1 {
  font: $title1Font;
}
```

Comment: For the reference, I'm going to have 9 different text types at the moment, so it's quite a bit stuff :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might take a look at @extend.

```
.font-one { 
  font-family: sans-serif;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.2em;
}
```

You can basically just create your items and share the styles whenever you call the class `@extend .font-one`. Here's some more info: https://sass-lang.com/documentation/at-rules/extend

Comment: Tried Extending, that's so nice :) Do you think I should use `font:` inside extend (style, variant, weight, size, family included) or should I separate them?

Comment: Just depends on the scenario & at some point your personal preference... files can quickly become hard to manage/find what you're looking for so focus on how you work. If you like extending you're going to love mixins; it takes variables: https://www.toptal.com/css/sass-mixins-keep-your-stylesheets-dry . Happy coding!